# Give variable to makeprg

Tags: vimscript, quickfix, variables

I'm trying to put the output of a command into a QuickFix list when a particular key is pressed. That command takes as its argument the word under the cursor, so my function looks basically like this (example; `ls` is not actually my command):

```
set makeprg=ls\ $*

function MyFunction()
    let word = expand("<cword>")
    silent make word
    copen
endfunction
```

And what it does is call with the literal word `word`. If I use a `$` before it, then the literal `$` is used also.

How do I put the value of `word` into `make` instead of those four letters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most ex commands (except for :echo and :exe) take their arguments literally and do not evaluate VimScript expressions. To make that work, you need to wrap your command into an `:exe` command.

So you would need to do:

```
:exe "sil make" word
```

Have also a look the help `:h :exe`